# How to show injected props by Redux on console

Tags: redux, react-redux

I can change the states and update the UI by using `Redux`. But how to show injected props by Redux on console by using console like `console.log(this.props)` in run-time. I cannot. I've never seen the props.

Is there a way to show component (class) props -that are assigned from Redux store like the code below-?

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { iconSize: state.iconSize }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        setIconSize: (size) => dispatch(setIconSize(size))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example you can rewrite `mapStateToProps` function:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const props = { iconSize: state.iconSize };
  console.log(props);
  return props;
}
```

It will log props each time this function is invoked.

Comment: I already use this method. Anyway I accept your answer. Is there another method that may be used in the component?

Comment: @user3765109 could you describe you use case? You know which props are passed from redux-bindings, i.e. in  your case it is only `iconSize`, so you can just do `console.log(this.props.iconSize)`.

Comment: For instance when using `console.log()` function in the `render ()` function I cannot see props. I guess there is no way to do this. Also I passed the case. Thanks anyway.